# ReactiveCocoa: dispose receiver of replayLazily

Tags: reactive-cocoa

I'm using ReactiveCocoa to compose complex signal of the following structure:

```
RACSignal* data1FromNetwork = ...;
RACSignal* data1FromNetworkHub = [data1FromNetwork replayLazily];
RACSignal* derivedData = [data1FromNetworkHub flattenMap:...];
RACSignal* data2FromNetwork = ...;
RACSignal* result = [RACSignal combineLatest:@[data1FromNetworkHub, derivedData, data2FromNetwork] reduce:...];
```

Signal `data1FromNetwork` is implemented as a network call, but has multiple subscribers - `derivedData` and in `combineLatest:reduce:`. So to avoid duplicating network calls, I use `replayLazily` to create a hub signal, that can be used for multiple subscriptions.

When I cancel `result`, all subscriptions to the hub signal get disposed, but the subscription between the hub signal and `data1FromNetwork` itself remains. So `data1FromNetwork` does not get cancelled. Underlying network request completes, `RACReplaySubject` created inside `replayLazily` gets notified, and data process stops at this point without any visible effect.

This is acceptable, but can be done better - I'd like all network activity to be cancelled as well. Can this be achieved using built-in RAC operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be represented like that using `-[RACMulticastConnection autoconnect]`:

```
RACSignal* data1FromNetwork = ...;

RACSignal* data1FromNetworkHub = [[data1FromNetwork publish] autoconnect];
// Or below if you want replaying behavior.
// RACSignal* data1FromNetworkHub = [[data1FromNetwork multicast:RACReplaySubject.subject] autoconnect];

RACSignal* derivedData = [data1FromNetworkHub flattenMap:...];
RACSignal* data2FromNetwork = ...;
RACSignal* result = [RACSignal combineLatest:@[data1FromNetworkHub, derivedData, data2FromNetwork] reduce:...];
```

When the signal returned by `-autoconnect` got to have no subscribers, the underlying signal (`data1FromNetwork` in this case) would be disposed.